# Read android device info from windows

Tags: android

Is it possible to get android device info (e.g. firmware version) from windows, when device is connected with PC by USB cable?
As I understand AT commands are not available. I was trying to use "adb", but I cannot see any usefull options. Maybe there is some text file with device info on the filesystem of the phone, so I could use "adb shell" to read this file?
Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use for example

```
adb -e shell getprop ro.build.display.id
```

to obtain something like

```
sdk-eng 2.1 ERD79 22607 test-keys
```

If you have more than one device or emulator, use

```
adb devices
```

to identify them and then use `-s serialno` in adb command line